# where can i find varnish log files? /var/log/varnish is empty

Tags: logging, varnish

I'm trying to read log files of Varnish server in Ubuntu environment.

I actually never used Varnish before.

so...I cd to /var/log/varnish, but the folder is empty.

it tells me that I have to configure my varnish server to save logs...is that true?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

by default varnish will not log anywhere.. you have to run a command to get it to show logs

You can run the command

```
varnishncsa
```

For more info on how to use that command to write to a log instead of stdout

http://www.go2linux.org/linux/2011/05/configure-varnish-logs-varnishnsca-logrotate-and-awstats-1014

Comment: The most stupid name for log command that you would never guess.

Comment: I looked all over the internet for this. Not only is it a difficult name, it's also buried deep where no one can find it.

Comment: You can also do `service varnishncsa start`

Comment: ncsa goes back to pre-apache webserver and is the name of the log format https://www.loganalyzer.net/log-analyzer/apache-combined-log.html. I agree though it's a stupid name

Answer (score 3):

We could use `varnishlog` too, a better remembered name compared with `varnishncsa`.

We need run it with **root privilege** - `sudo varnishlog`, otherwise somethime it will said `VSM: Could not get hold of varnishd, is it running?`.

For writing log to file, we could run `sudo varnishlog -w <filename>`.

> `-w <filename>`
>   Redirect output to file.
>   The file will be overwritten unless the `-a` option was specified.
>   If the application receives a `SIGHUP` in daemon mode the file will be  reopened allowing the old one to be rotated away.
>   The file can then be read by varnishlog and other tools with the  `-r`  option,  unless  the `-A` option was specified. This option is required when running in daemon mode.

For reading the log file, we could run `sudo varnishlog -r <filename>`.

> `-r <filename>`
>   Read log in binary file format from this file. The file can be created with `varnishlog -w filename`.

Comment: Solution suggested by you helped me. Thank you.